# Run sikulixapi (1.1.0) as admin

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script

How to run sikulixapi as admin?

Does anyone have an example or explanation?

A saw this command `java -jar <path-to>\sikulix.jar` on the internet.

But my Sikulis import in intellij project like an external library.

Comment: Please describe your actual problem. Why do you need to run it as admin?

Comment: You could right click on the jar file and do `Run as Admin`, or open a CMD prompt with `Run as Admin` and the execute that `java -jar <path-to\sikulix.jar>`.

Comment: If you are using OSX or Linux use sudo, ie sudo java -jar <path-to>\sikulix.jar